# Conda YML file prompts "Please add an explicit pip dependency"

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install additional libraries for ML.

I'm using a file called tools.yml. Which is built like this

```
 # conda create --name tensorflow-cpu python=3.8
 # conda install jupyter
 # conda install nb_conda
 # conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
 # conda env update --file tools.yml
dependencies:
    - jupyter
    - scikit-learn
    - scipy
    - pandas
    - pandas-datareader
    - matplotlib
    - pillow
    - tqdm
    - requests
    - h5py
    - pyyaml
    - flask
    - boto3
    - pip:
        - bayesian-optimization
        - gym
        - kaggle
```

But when I run the conda environment update I get this warning

> **Warning**: you have pip-installed dependencies in your environment file, but you do not list pip itself as one of your conda dependencies. Conda may not use the correct pip to install your packages, and they may end up in the wrong place.  Please add an explicit pip dependency. I'm adding one for you, but still nagging you.

Which fills the cmd screen. But as far as I'm aware pip is listed a dependency already in the file. Sorry if this seems obvious I'm new.

Answer (score 12):

The line

```yaml
dependencies:
...
  - pip:  # this line
     ...
```

is parsed as a list from which to generate a `requirements.txt` file to then give to `pip`, but is not considered an explicit directive to install the `pip` package. To avoid the warning, try:

```yaml
dependencies:
...
  - pip   # this is a dependency
  - pip:  # this starts a "requirements.txt" list
     ...
```

It's sort of pedantic, and the code does automatically add a `pip` as dependency as per the warning, so it's really not consequential. There's likely an Issue on the GitHub repo documenting the genesis of this warning message.

Answer (score 1):

@merv's answer is technically correct but didn't explain the warning message and what you should do to follow best practices.

One of the reasons to use Conda is *reproducibility*, that is, to make sure that your code works exactly the same way during development and deployment, across different machines.
The way Conda improves reproducibility is by making sure that the dependencies are exactly the same every time the (virtual) environment is built.

Since Pip is often used in conjunction with Conda, it's important to make sure that its behavior is also consistent, otherwise the dependencies might change. Hence the warning message:

> Conda may not use the correct pip to install your packages, and they may end up in the wrong place.

The best practice is to explicitly define your pip dependency *and* to pin its version so that the next time the environment is built, the exact same pip and packages are reproduced. So, you should work out what pip you're using and then add a dependency like so:

```
dependencies:
...
  - pip=xxx   # this is a dependency
  - pip:      # this starts a "requirements.txt" list
     - package1~=yyy
     - package2~=zzz
     ...
```

The warning will disappear and you'll have a more reproducible codebase.